# Dog isn't as playful as he has been for the past 5 months

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology, play

My German Shepherd dog is roughly 1 year old, male and he has been playful and energetic. Now, when we try to get him to play, he doesn't seem like he wants to. Could this be related to joint health? If not, what could possibly be the problem? He has been having some problems with his pancreas and we're not quite sure if this is related to the problem or not.

Comment: You have identified an existing internal organ health issue, and you have noted change in behavior.  You need to contact your vet as soon as possible. Please post you vets response as answer so others can learn from your experience.

Comment: Is he under treatment?

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton I'm still waiting for the information so I don't know anything yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weather changes can have an affect on a pet's activity level as can changes in the household routine. If his health is fine, it might be that he has outgrown the puppy playfulness so you might have spend more time engaging him in play time. Does he have a favorite toy or game! I find it helpful to schedule time to play with my pets each day. They come to expect it and it really helps with bonding too. Good luck!